# Can i use singleton scope for an Akka supervisor Actor in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, scope, akka

I have a supervisor Actor which is responsible for throttling requests to a number of upstream systems. This supervisor actor creates child actors with a scope of prototype which do the actual heavy lifting of sending the requests.

I want to create just a single instance of my supervisor actor, i know it is recommended to give Akka Actors a scope of prototype however in this situation can i use a singleton scoped Actor to ensure all requests use the same supervisor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, did not see that one before responding to your other question.

The reason that prototype scope should be used, is that Akka will restart actors on failures. If you have singleton scope this might lead to problems. However, Akka will not create new instances of your actor randomly. When you create an actor using actorOf, there will be an actor created each time, but only one actor (unless you use a router of course). So as long as you create your actors correctly you will only have one instance of this actor, and the ActorRef you got back from actorOf will always point to an instance of your actor. When exceptions occur, the actor will be stopped and a new instance is started, the actorRef will still point to that actor.

Comment: thanks @pushy, so if i have created my Supervisor Actor using the ActorOf syntax then it doesnt matter whether it is marked as prototype or singleton because there will only ever be a single Actor created and subsequent use of the ActorRef only contain a reference to the Actor?? is this correct

Comment: I should have been more detailed..I'm using Akka's TimerBasedThrottler class to implement throttling in my application. This class allows you to specify a throttling rate when creating an Actor. The new ActorRef can then specify a child Actor which messages can be forwarded onto. Messages will not be dealt with any faster than the throttling rate specified during creation of the first actor...this is why i wanted to ensure i only have a single instance of the Actor which defines the throttling rate

Comment: hey @niloc, that should work fine. Like I said, you need to make sure that actorOf is only called once for this actor, then there only will be one. When that actor encounters an exception it will be restarted, which results in a new instance, but that should make no difference in your case.

Comment: @pushy "So as long as you create your actors correctly you will only have one instance of this actor, and the ActorRef you got back from actorOf will always point to an instance of your actor." Assuming, I am not using router...What happens if I call actorOf() from different places in my application. Do they all get the same instance of actor? OR each time new actor is created since scope is set to prototype?